# How to transform a column containing n-d vectors into multiple columns ? Python

Tags: python, pandas

Let's assume that I have a pandas dataset and its column A contains n dimensional vectors. I would like to split this column into multiple columns. Basically, my dataset looks like :

```
A              B       C  
[1,0,2,3,5]   ...     ...
[4,5,3,2,1]   ...     ...
.........................
```

And I want to have :

```
A0 A1 A2 A3 A4 B    C
1  0  2  3  5  ...  ...
4  5  3  2  1  ...  ...
.......................
```

I can solve this problem by using apply function and for loops, I think. But, I imagine that there exists a better (faster, easier to read, ...) way to do so.

**Edit: My post gets marked as duplicate. But the given answers have a solution which leads to more rows. I want more columns as shown above.**
Thanks,

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53218931/how-to-unnest-explode-a-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe) is what you are looking for.

Comment: This is not what I want...

Comment: The solutions in the marked questions actually do more that what you need. You could try modify them to see what works.